# Flutter Firebase FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase using futurebuilder but im getting this error anyone know how to fix it ?

[image]

**Fetching Function**

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getProduct() async {
    var product = await instance.collection('ürünler').doc().get();
    return product;
  }
```

**Body**

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
                    future: getProduct(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Text('Data coming'),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        return 
                         
                                 
                        ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                child: Image(
                                width: width * 1 / 4,
                                height: height * 1 / 6,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: NetworkImage(                                  
                                snapshot.data.data()[index]['image']),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
```

Comment: you didn't add a **itemCount** for GridView.builder

Comment: still same i think  im going to use stream builder with subscribtion